# How can I test to see if a defaultdict(set) is empty in Python

Tags: python, set

I have a defaultdict `fishparts = defaultdict(set)` that has elements assigned to it but is periodically cleared using `.clear()` What I need is some way to test if the set is clear or not so I can do some other work in the function below.

```
def bandpassUniqReset5(player,x,epochtime):
    score = 0
    if lastplay[player] < (epochtime - 300):
        fishparts[player].clear()
    lastplay[player] = epochtime
    for e in x:
        # right here I want to do a check to see if the "if" conditional above has cleared fishparts[player] before I do the part below
        if e not in fishparts[player]:
            score += 1
        fishparts[player].add(e)
    return str(score)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sets, like all Python containers, are considered False when empty:

```
if not fishparts[player]:
    # this set is empty
```

See [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Demo:

```
>>> if not set(): print "I am empty"
... 
I am empty
>>> if set([1]): print "I am not empty"
... 
I am not empty
```

Comment: Perfect exactly what I was looking for